# SQL nvarchar is invalid for sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL and I have table that looks like this:

```
Id  Name   Payd  Note
1   John   5.00  R:8days;U:5$
2   Adam   5.00  R:8days;
3   John   10.00 R:8days;
4   John   10.00 R:8days;
5   Adam   15.00 R:30days;
```

I want to make something like this:

```
  Id  Name Usage     5.00 10.00 15.00 Sum
    1   John  5      5.00 20.00 0     25.00
    2   Adam         5.00 0     15.00 20.00
```

I want to check that note column if there is 'U:5$' in it and then add a 5 to that customer that has 'U:5$' in note column, if it doesnt it doesnt add anything.

My code looks like this:

```
;with cte as (
select Customer, PaydAmount, PaydAmount as Payd, Note as Usage
from t1
)
select 
    Customer, Usage
    ,[4.00] = ISNULL([4.00],0)
    ,[5.00] = ISNULL([5.00],0)
    ,[9.00] = ISNULL([9.00],0)
    ,[10.00] = ISNULL([10.00],0)
    ,[15.00] = ISNULL([15.00],0)
    ,[18.00] = ISNULL([18.00],0)
    ,[20.00] = ISNULL([20.00],0)
    ,[25.00] = ISNULL([25.00],0)
    ,[50.00] = ISNULL([50.00],0)
    ,[Payd] =ISNULL([4.00],0) + ISNULL([5.00],0) + ISNULL([9.00],0) + ISNULL([10.00],0) + ISNULL([15.00],0) + ISNULL([18.00],0) + ISNULL([20.00],0) + ISNULL([25.00],0) + ISNULL([50.00],0)
    from cte
    pivot (
        sum(PaydAmount) for Payd in ([4.00],[5.00],[9.00], [10.00], [15.00],[18.00], [20.00], [25.00], [50.00]))pvt
        order by Customer;
```

Comment: Your output is complicated.  What happens after the usage column?

Comment: ok, the amounts that are payd are static so it could be payd 4.00$, 5.00$, 9.00$... and in these coulumns there are summed all values that have been payd the amount that is the same as column name. For example john payd 2 times 4$ then there is 8$ at 4.00 column by John. Sum at the end is sum of all payd amounts. I just want to check if there is U:5$ in note and then add 5 in 5 column by the customer that actualy had U5:$ in his note.

Comment: From the error message it looks like your amounts are stored in `NVARCHAR` columns. Either make sure they are stored in `MONEY` or `DECIMAL` type columns, or `CAST` the data to `MONEY` or `DECIMAL` in the `SUM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your full output represents.  But the first three columns are easy to get using conditional aggregation:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,
       name,
       max(case when note like '%U:5$' then 5 end) as usage,
       sum(case when payd = 5.00 then payd else 0 end) as [5.00],
       sum(case when payd = 10.00 then payd else 0 end) as [10.00],
       sum(case when payd = 15.00 then payd else 0 end) as [15.00],
       sum(payd) as total
from cte
group by name;
```

Note that the columns for 5, 10, and 15 sort of assume that the value in `payd` is a decimal/numeric type.  Equality comparisons on floats are not recommended.

Comment: This works just fine, can i ask you how could i group by Payd

Comment: @vidooo . . . This question is about grouping by `name`.  If you have another question, then ask *another* question.  I believe this answers the question here.